# Create a Custom approval workflow in Moss 2007 using Visual studio 2005

Tags: 2007, workflow

I want to create custom sequential document approval workflow and then have some more functionality to add to it once it's all done, I have done a little research and it seems like I would need to create a form which the approval will fill to approve or reject a document when uploaded to the doc lib. Can I use an out of box approval workflow with this custom workflow? so I have to create a custom form for it. If so can anyone provide a link to such an article?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me right the SharePoint 2007 SDK had as one of its samples, the Out of the Box Approval workflow which would be a great start for your project!

If you look at the description of the v1.2 version of the SDK you will see the item Approval Workflow Sample.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861863(v=office.12).aspx

**•Workflow Samples**

◦
Custom Workflow Report Query Generator

◦
Custom Workflow Report XLSX Injector

◦
Visual Studio Workflow Templates

◦
Enterprise Content Management Workflow Activities

◦
List Item Activities

◦
Hello World Sequential Workflow

◦
State Based Approval Workflow

◦
Modification Workflow

◦
Replication and Contact Selector Workflow

◦
Intersystem Purchase Order

◦
Confidential Approval Workflow

◦
Group Approval Workflow

◦
**Approval Workflow Sample**

◦
Multi-Stage Workflow

◦
Server-side Collect Signatures Workflow